# Transactional send and receive

Tags: servicebus

Is it possible to perform a receive from one queue, and send to another within the same transaction? e.g.:

```
using (var tx = new TransactionScope())
{
    var inMsg = recv.Receive();
    var val = msg.GetBody<int>();
    var outMsg = new BrokeredMessage(val + 1);
    sender.Send(outMsg);
    inMsg.Complete();

    tx.Complete();
}
```

The above appears to give me an exception suggesting it isn't possible:

> "The Transaction may have timed out or attempted to span multiple top-level entities such as Queue or Topic."

But surely this is a very common requirement? Is there a way around this?

(This is using Service Bus for Windows Server, if that makes a difference)

Answer (score 1):

There is restriction of only one top level messaging entity being able to participate in a transaction.

More info here

http://geekswithblogs.net/asmith/archive/2012/04/02/149176.aspx